# React App 404 Error after refreshing the web page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My react application works fine when it loads in browser however when I attempt to refresh the page it will give me a 404 Error. Attached below is my App.js code. I am fairly new to React so any tips would help.

````
import Layout from './components/Layout'
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Work from './components/Work';
import Projects from './components/Projects';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route index path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route index path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route index path="/work" element={<Work />} />
        <Route index path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;```
````

Comment: Where is it deployed? I suspect the server environment may have some role here. If the home route "/" works okay even with a refresh but the other pages give you 404 when you refresh, it might be that not all routes are forwarded correctly to index file.

Comment: @IrfanullahJan that is correct, the home route refreshes but the rest give me a 404.

Comment: How are you running/serving the app? This certain appears to be an issue with how you are hosting the app. The server should redirect page requests for sub-routes to the root index.html file. Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to see if any of the sections are relevant to your server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I noticed your react app.js structure was off point, sorry but if the pages are going to be linked from your home then do not index them. and your home path link straight to the layout and not home can you explain why. here is the change i made removed the Layout.

the layout should be used as a general component for all pages and not a standalone page.

```
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Work from './components/Work';
import Projects from './components/Projects';

function App() {
  return (
     <Routes>
       <Route  path="/" element={<Home />} />
       <Route  path="/about" element={<About />} />
       <Route  path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
       <Route  path="/work" element={<Work />} />
       <Route  path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
     </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You are correct about using the `index` prop, but why did you remove the `Layout` layout route? The easy fix is simply to remove the `index` prop from all but the `Home` route. Overall this answer doesn't address the issue OP has with serving up the app. This should be a comment instead, or an addendum to an answer that addresses the OPs issue.